# convert MATLAB optimise function to julia

Tags: matlab, julia, nlopt

I am trying to convert a Matlab fmincon optimisation function to julia.
but without much luck.

I think NLopt or IPopt can be used.
the default examples work but when i try to change the values it doesnt seem to iterate.

```
using NLopt
count = 0 # keep track of # function evaluations
function myfunc(x::Vector, grad::Vector)
    if length(grad) > 0
        grad[1] = 0
        grad[2] = 0.5/sqrt(x[2])
    end
    global count
    count::Int += 1
    println("f_$count($x)")

    sqrt(x[2])
end

function myconstraint(x::Vector, grad::Vector, a, b)
    if length(grad) > 0
        grad[1] = 3a * (a*x[1] + b)^2
        grad[2] = -1
    end
    (a*x[1] + b)^3 - x[2]
end

opt = Opt(:LD_MMA, 2)
lower_bounds!(opt, [-Inf, 0.])
xtol_rel!(opt,1e-4)

min_objective!(opt, myfunc)
inequality_constraint!(opt, (x,g) -> myconstraint(x,g,2,0), 1e-8)
inequality_constraint!(opt, (x,g) -> myconstraint(x,g,-1,1), 1e-8)

(minf,minx,ret) = optimize(opt, [1.234, 5.678])
println("got $minf at $minx after $count iterations (returned $ret)")
```

This one works fine. it gives 2 results and 11 iterations

```
using NLopt
count = 0 # keep track of # function evaluations
function myfunc(x)
    x[1]^2 + 5*x[2] - 3
end
function myconstraint(x)
    100*x[1] + 2000*x[2] == 100
end

opt = Opt(:LD_MMA, 2)
lower_bounds!(opt, [0, 0])
upper_bounds!(opt,[10,5])
xtol_rel!(opt,1e-10)

min_objective!(opt, myfunc);
inequality_constraint!(opt, (x) -> myconstraint(x), 1e-10)

(minf,minx,ret) = optimize(opt, [0.1,0.1])
```

This doesnt work, It just gives a result and 0 iterations

```
using NLopt
count = 0 # keep track of # function evaluations
function myfunc(x::Vector, grad::Vector)
    x[1]^2 + 5*x[2] - 3
end
function myconstraint(result::Vector, x::Vector, grad::Vector)
    100*x[1] + 2000*x[2] == 100
end

opt = Opt(:LD_MMA, 2)
lower_bounds!(opt, [0., 0.])
upper_bounds!(opt, [10.,5.])
xtol_rel!(opt,1e-4)

min_objective!(opt, myfunc)
inequality_constraint!(opt, (x,g) -> myconstraint(x), 1e-8)

(minf,minx,ret) = optimize(opt, [0., 0.])#even with [5.,10.]
```

this just gives me a result and 0 iterations.

anyone any idea what i a doing wrong?

Comment: There is something funny about `myconstraint`. When using `NLopt`, your inequality constraint function should return the value of some function `f(x)`, where your inequality constraint is expressed as `f(x) <= 0`. See [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Introduction) for more detail. Your function `myconstraint` appears to be returning a type `Bool`?

Comment: @ColinTBowers If i remove the == and put = it gives me an error, "LoadError: syntax: "*100,x[1])" is not a valid function argument name"

Comment: Yes, because that is not valid syntax for a function. Assuming the inequality constraint you are after is `100*x[1] + 2000*x[2] <= 100`, then your `myconstraint` function should return `100*x[1] + 2000*x[2] - 100` since this satisfies the `f(x) <= 0` syntax that NLopt accepts. Optionally, you can also include the gradient vector. If you're still having trouble, please include in some sort of mathematical notation in the question the exact constraint you want to implement.

Comment: How'd you go with this? Once you work out the syntax and structure of `NLopt`, it really is a fantastic library to work with.

Comment: only just got round to trying it sorry, i got it to work by replacing '(x,g) -> myconstraint(x)' with 'myconstraint', and by putting 'return' at the beginning of each function return line.
# So that works for inequality_constraint but I cant get it to run if i change it to an equality_constraint without changing anything else?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, please mark the question answered. Otherwise, let me know where you think it is lacking and I will try to improve it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a tough time reconstructing what you've done based on the comment marathon, so instead I thought I would just provide code indicating how I would have solved this problem. Note, the following code assumes your inequality constraint is `100*x[1] + 2000*x[2] <= 100`:

```
using NLopt
function myfunc(x::Vector{Float64}, grad::Vector{Float64})
    if length(grad) > 0
        grad[1] = 2 * x[1]
        grad[2] = 5
    end
    xOut = x[1]^2 + 5*x[2] - 3
    println("Obj func = " * string(xOut))
    return(xOut)
end
function myconstraint(x::Vector{Float64}, grad::Vector{Float64})
    if length(grad) > 0
        grad[1] = 100
        grad[2] = 2000
    end
    xOut = 100*x[1] + 2000*x[2] - 100
    println("Constraint val = " * string(xOut))
    return(xOut)
end
opt = Opt(:LD_MMA, 2)
lower_bounds!(opt, [0, 0])
upper_bounds!(opt,[10,5])
xtol_rel!(opt,1e-10)
min_objective!(opt, myfunc);
inequality_constraint!(opt, myconstraint, 1e-10)

(minf,minx,ret) = optimize(opt, [0.1,0.1])
```

There are three main differences between my code and yours:

1. I've explicitly included the gradient function updates. This will make the convergence routine more efficient for any gradient-based algorithm (of which MMA is one).
2. I'm printing out the values of my objective function and constraint function at each step. This is useful for debugging purposes, and to get some idea of what is happening under the hood.
3. I've made it very clear in my code that the return value from my constraint function is `f(x)`, where the constraint is defined by the equation `f(x) <= 0`. This is the appropriate syntax for use with `NLopt`.

You stated in the comments that you are getting an error when you try to change `inequality_constraint!` to `equality_constraint!`. This is because your algorithm of choice (MMA) only supports inequality constraints. A description of the `NLopt` algorithms can be found [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms). Note:

> only MMA and SLSQP support arbitrary nonlinear inequality constraints, and only SLSQP supports nonlinear equality constraints

So, switch your algorithm to `:LD_SLSQP`, and voila, you can now switch your inequality constraint to an equality constraint.

Comment: Hi where is the best place to look for a full understaniding of julia syntax, and libraries available to julia, as i have not found anywhere that states everything that is and is not allowed in julia yet.

Comment: @f1wade I found the [official docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/) to be well-written and comprehensive for the `Base` library. If they're a bit heavy going, [this website](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/) gives a quick overview, although some of the material, e.g. dictionary syntax is now (I think) out of date. For available libraries, check [here](http://pkg.julialang.org/), but I would also strongly recommend joining the [julia-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users) group, and just skim the daily updates. I pick up a lot of new stuff from there.